# Node.js & Crypto: Store the current state of a crypto.createHash Instance to reuse it later

Tags: node.js, cryptography, checksum

#### How to store the current state of `crypto.createHash('sha1')` (after it got filled with `hash.update(buffer)`) to use it at another `http request` which might occur at a different process of node.js?

*I imagine doing something like this:*

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    hash   = someDatabase.read('hashstate')    // continue with filled hash
             || crypto.createHash('sha1');     // start a new hash

// update the hash
someObj.on('data', function(buffer){
    hash.update(buffer);
});
someObj.on('end', function(){
    // store the current state of hash to retrieve it later (this won't work:)
    someDatabase.write('hashstate', hash);

    if(theEndOfAllRequests){
        // create the result of multiple http requests
        hash.digest('hex');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you are doing the multi-part uploading?

Comment: The client sends a file in max 3 MB parts - each of the part request gets sent from [Fine Uploader 3.3](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader) with `chunking.enabled = true`. Node listens for every request and writes the recieved data to a `new WriteStream` with `stream.write(buffer)`. At this point I also use `hash.update(buffer)` which successfully creates the checksum for data of the max. 3 MB request. But I struggle to carry the state of the written buffer (after `hash.update`) to the next request to continue the calculation of the overall file sha1 checksum (combined of all requests)

Comment: Can you put those details in the question and add the actual code you are using? Please show for instance how you know when all the chunks have been written and such.

Comment: I tried to strip down my code as good as possible: http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/bYVga/ hope it helps!

Comment: How are you running the multiple processes that the reqs might come in on?  Cluster?

Comment: @AaronDufour: yes, cluster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options I can come up with, with varying trade-offs.  The big thing to note is that `crypto` doesn't expose partial state of its hash functions, so there's no way to directly implement your plan of saving state to a db.

Option 1 involves diving into a hash function, which can be tricky.  Fortunately, there [already is one written in javascript](https://github.com/creationix/git-sha1/blob/master/git-sha1.js).  Again, it doesn't expose state, but I don't expect that would be a terribly difficult code transformation.  I believe the entire state is stored in the variables defined at the top of `create` - `h0-4`, `block`, `offset`, `shift`, and `totalLength`.  Then, you could save state in a db as you planned.

Options 2 involves using `crypto` and passing data to be hashed between processes.  This is a lot easier to work with, I think, but also a lot slower.  In a few quick tests, it looks like messages will pass around at a rate of about 2.5-3MB/sec, so each 3MB chunk will take about 1.5 seconds (you can only pass strings, so I expect you'll need a Base64 conversion which costs an extra 33%).  To do this, you would use `process.send` to send the data along with identifying id.  The master process would use `worker.on` on each worker to get the messages, and keep a mapping of ids to hashing objects.  Finally, you would want to have a flag in the message that tells the master it is receiving the last message, and it would `worker.send` the resulting hash (received in the worker with `process.on`).

I'd be happy to elaborate on whichever of these sounds most suitable.

Comment: If it were me, I'd spend the time on option 1 unless you're absolutely certain that level of performance isn't necessary.  Also, just because it's cool.  I've taken a few different concepts and started working on chunked/streaming processors, it's such a powerful and minimal way to accomplish things, it's the way node is built.  If you can buy into the concept wholesale you can do an awful lot with what node gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all you need to do is create a new hash for each "related request group", store it in an object directly in your code, and keep updating that hash independently of any other unrelated requests that are going on.

All that's required is that you somehow are able to name a group of related requests, so that you know they belong together, and make sure the scope of your long-lived hashes encompass the processing functions.

Something like the following (this assumes only one group of requests occurring at any given moment, and doesn't worry about naming the request group to make sure you don't get crossover):

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    // don't create it here, but set the scope so it will live between requests
    hash = null;

someObj.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // we have to have some data in chunk that allows us
    // to relate this request to its fellow requests, or assume
    // that no unrelated requests are occurring at this time
    // var name = chunk.this_is_my_name;
    if (hash === null) hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    hash.update(chunk);
});

someObj.on('end', function(){
    if(theEndOfAllRequests){
        // create the result of multiple http requests
        var digest = hash.digest('hex');

        /* use the digest */

        hash = null; // so it can be created fresh for the next set of requests
    }
});
```

Comment: He has multiple processes that might get different chunks of the same file, which your answer does not solve.

Comment: Ah, I missed that!  Then, as you state in your answer, the most straight forward option is to pass the chunks to a single parent or management process that computes the hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `hash.update` multiple times as data comes in.

Hard to say exactly what you should do without knowing how you are getting the chunks, but here's a simple example with v1 Streams:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
var data = // incoming file data

data.on('data', function(chunk){
  hash.update(chunk);
});
data.on('end', function(){
  var sha = hash.digest('hex');

  // Do something with it
})
```

Comment: I should have written "requests" instead of "chunks" (I just updated the question, sorry about that). The functions above are already included in my script; I want to transfer the state of `hash` to a completly different http request to continue `updating` it with another on('data') function.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus You should be able to keep the `hash` instance around until each individual upload request has completed.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to ask: a solution to keep the `hash` instance around - but how? Is there a way to pass a variable to another `http request` (which even might be on a different server)?

Comment: It is the same for the `hash` object as for any other object on the server I suppose. But it sounds more logical to me to calculate the hash at the point where you aggregate the results of the various HTTP POST or HTTP PUT operations. Normally the higher end functions don't expose the intermediate hash data.

Comment: Yes I could just calculate the hash again after Node recieved the last chunk request, but I want to avoid this, because it would require to read the whole file again - which might take a while if the file is large. may you give me a hint on how to pass the state of `hash` to the next request?