# How can I get the checksum of a (large) file using ExpressJS/Connect/Crypto?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, checksum

I need to generate a checksum for a large file (.ISO), on file upload. I'm using ExpressJS/Connect to handle an upload request via POST (multipart)

```
  //express setup app.js
  app.use('/upload',express.bodyParser({
      defer : true, //enable progress event
      keepExtensions : true,
      limit : app.locals.fileLimit,
      uploadDir : path.join( __dirname, '..', 'tmp'),
      hash : true //this doesnt appear to do anything
  }));

  //express route routes.js
  app.post("/upload", function(req, res){

      var fs     = require('fs');
      var format = require('util').format;

      req.form.hash = true; //this doesnt return the hash for some reason

      req.form.on('fileBegin', function(err) {
         log.info("Starting new upload...");
      });

      req.form.on('file', function(name, file) {
          fs.rename(file.path, req.form.uploadDir + "/" + file.name);
        console.info(file);
      });

      req.form.on('error', function(err) {
         log.error('error',err);
         req.resume();
      });



      req.form.on('field', function(field, value) {
         log.info("Passed Field (%s=%s)...",field,value);
      });

      //this part event never gets called for some reason but
      //I imagine this is where you might do a hash update
      req.form.on('part', function(part){
        console.log('PART upload %s %s', part.name, part.filename);
        var out = fs.createWriteStream('../tmpstrm/' + part.filename);
        part.pipe(out);
      });


      req.form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
          var percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;
          console.info( "PROGRESS :"+ ((bytesReceived / bytesExpected)*100) + "% uploaded");
      });

      req.form.on('end', function() {
          var fileInfo = format('\nuploaded %s (%d Kb) to %s as %s'
            , req.files.upload.name
            , req.files.upload.size / 1024 | 0
            , req.files.upload.path
            , req.body.title);

          res.locals.fileInfo = fileInfo; //renders info in jade

          res.render('media/index');
      });

  });
```

I couldn't find too much information on my particular question; it's probably not a typical use-case. But the one question I did find had a brief example of [how to update the hash on a data event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755738/node-js-crypto-store-the-current-state-of-a-crypto-createhash-instance-to-reu)

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
var data = // incoming file data

data.on('data', function(chunk){
  hash.update(chunk);
});
data.on('end', function(){
  var sha = hash.digest('hex');

  // Do something with it
})
```

I'm new to streaming, chunks, etc, so some guidance here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some example code you might find helpful in my writers-digest npm module source code:

https://github.com/focusaurus/writers-digest/blob/ab52ffca6e989ca657dc449e05ff258c428fa3af/index.js#L38

But basically you have 2 approaches:

1. Allow the bodyParser to stream the HTTP request body to the filesystem, and then subsequently compute the checksum by streaming data from the filesystem (using the writers-digest code as an example).
2. You can try to compute the checksum while the actual HTTP request body is arriving by binding event handler functions to the `req` objects `data` and `end` events. You should be able to do this while the bodyParser also streams it to disk. Just make sure the events are bound early enough so you don't miss any chunks.

Comment: Thank you! You're a regular, helpful resource on the NodeJS questions. Some background info -- this is my first pass at just trying to get this to work, in a follow up version this is supposed to redirect the write stream to another server on the network, so the file won't be stored on the machine running node. Do you have any thoughts on how to handle that? Will these two methods still work for that?

Comment: So yes you can proxy the stream to a destination server, but bear in mind that's another point of failure and unreliability. I would stick with a simpler store & forward model, but in theory you could just proxy the file content on to an upstream server (or even maybe confgure nginx to do that for you). Tough to address that big of an architecture question as a stackoverflow comment, though. Could do it via an http://airpair.com session perhaps though.